# How to show that this series converges in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Given the series $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}c_k e^{ikx}$.
Show that if the coefficients $c_k$ satisfy:
There exists a constant L>0 such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$  $\exists m \in \mathbb{N} : |c_k|\leq Lk^m$
Then the series converges in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$

First I looked up the Definition of  "converges in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$":

For $A_n  \in \mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$ and $A \in \mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$
the sequence $A_n \rightarrow A$ in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$ if
$\langle A_n,f \rangle \rightarrow \langle A,f \rangle$ for every testfunction $f \in \mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$.

The second convergence is the usual convergence in $\mathbb{R}$.

First I rewrote the series so It looks "nicer":

$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}c_k e^{ikx}=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k e^{ikx} +\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{-k} e^{-ikx} )$
As I don't know to which function the series converges I thought that I would try to show that it is a Cauchy series.
This means I need to show
$|\langle A_p,f \rangle - \langle A_q,f \rangle| \leq \epsilon$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$.

$|\langle A_p,f \rangle - \langle A_q,f \rangle|=
|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) (\sum_{k=q}^{p}c_k e^{ikx} +\sum_{k=q}^{p}c_{-k} e^{-ikx}) dx| \leq 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| (|\sum_{k=q}^{p}c_k e^{ikx}| +|\sum_{k=q}^{p}c_{-k} e^{-ikx}|) dx \leq
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| (\sum_{k=q}^{p}Lk^m +\sum_{k=q}^{p}Lk^m ) dx=
2L \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| \sum_{k=q}^{p}k^m )$

I don't really know how to continue. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

**Edit:**

Using the hint I got from Alex Ortiz

Let $f \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$

$\langle e^{ikx},f(x) \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}f(x)dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{ik}f(x)dx$

Let M<N

$lim_{M,N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{M<|k|<N}c_k \langle e^{ikx},f(x) \rangle \leq lim_{M,N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{M<|k|<N}|c_k| \langle e^{ikx},f(x) \rangle \leq lim_{M,N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{M<|k|<N}L|k|^m \langle e^{ikx},f(x) \rangle = lim_{M,N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{M<|k|<N}L|k|^m (-1)^{m+1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{(i)^{m+1} (k)^{m+1}}f(x)dx=im_{M,N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{M<|k|<N}\frac{L}{k} (-1)^{m+1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{(i)^{m+1} }f(x)dx$

More in general, I can partially integrate as often as I like. This way I can guarantee that for every $\epsilon$ and all m,n the absolute value of the partial sum is still less then $\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy the assumption about the coefficients down correctly? The order of the quantifiers matters. $$\exists L\ \forall k\ \exists m:|c_k|\le L|k|^m$$ is the order you have written down, but I suspect is not what was intended since you can choose the sequence $\{c_k\}$ in such a manner that the result doesn't hold ($c_k = |k|^{|k|}$ should suffice as a counterexample). I believe the assumption should be
$$\exists L\ \exists m\ \forall k:|c_k|\le L|k|^m.$$ In other words, the sequence of coefficients has at most polynomial growth.

You are correct about the definition of convergence in $\mathcal D'$. In this case, it amounts to proving that for any fixed test function $f$, the sequence of real numbers $\{\langle \sum_{|k|<N}c_ke^{ikx},f(x)\rangle\}_{N=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{M,N\to\infty}\sum_{M<|k|<N}c_k\langle e^{ikx},f(x)\rangle=0.
$$
Here is a sketch of how to proceed. When you evaluate, $\langle e^{ikx},f(x)\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}f(x)\,dx$.

**Fact.** Since $f$ is a fixed test function, there is some $A>0$ so that $f(x)=0$ for all $|x| > A$.

Using the fact, try integrating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}f(x)\,dx$ by parts and see what you get.

Comment: You are right, I mixed up the order of the quantifiers.

Comment: I edited my post. I think I got it now.

Comment: @John.W: It looks like you got the right idea. The estimates you wrote need to be fixed a little here and there by putting absolute value signs in (at some points you have absolute values, and at other points they have disappeared), but overall this is the correct idea.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to write the idea down. Thank you very much.